# Statistical/Automated method for identifying a dataset suitable for Machine Learning Modelling

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, python, algorithms, automatic-algorithms

Given a folder which has 10k Excel files, ***the objective is to identify the datasets suitable for Machine Learning Modelling Approach.***

We use a script right now which performs this operation and call it as `No Model Possible` script.
Current logic for this script is based on *business rule* that:

1. Calculate the % of number of timestamps which are `boolean`, we save it in variable as `X`.
2. Calculate the % of number of timestamps for which the OP signal is not in the `given range`, we save it in variable as `Y`.
3. If any of the `two variables have % greater than 95%`, we label that dataset as `No_Model_Possible` dataset.

Now, since i have explained the existing logic, our motive is to improve the same.
**Requirement**: I am looking for some solid Statistical tests that we can perform on the given dataset and then classify the dataset to be `Model Possible` or `No Model Possible`.
**Note**:

*- Dataset can have a shape of (200k,2k) including the Target Tag.*
*- Features and Target Tag may/may not be Normally Distributed.*.
*- One main feature is `Timestamp` with minute interval.*

Comment: This must depend on context, tell us more about that!

Comment: Well the only context i can tell you is that the datasets are regarding Manufacturing units in a plant.

Comment: Figured it out, mostly, we can use the pct_change pandas method or first differencing order to identify any modular changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Major, criteria i was looking for any Modular changes/multiple oscillations to track.

Explored few methods like `Stationarity Test and Interdaily Stability`, but both of these methods have assumption of some kind of pattern/trend, which may/may not be present in our Target Feature.
And since we are doing Regression problem on a time series dataset due to certain challenges, it is important to acknowledge `No Model Possible scenarios, where there is no fluctuation/deviation observed in a the Op Signal(Target feature.)`

The below `pct_change()` and `diff()` method helps in identifying the extent of movement observed in the op signal.

```
def pct_change_diff(dataset,tag_name_col,threshold_val):
'''
1. Computing Percentage Change in a TIME SERIES beteen consecutive elements.
2. Computng First Difference in a TIME SERIES between consecutive elements.

There is no difference between the two methods apart from that, pct_chnage represents the value in %.


PCT CHANGE may become NAN is the values are constant at 0, so we opt for First Difference as our KPI value!
'''

dataset['pct_change'] = dataset.pct_change()
dataset['first_diff'] = dataset[tag_name_col].diff()

# Calculating the number if time stamps where no change/difference is observed
pct_change_zero = round((len(dataset[dataset['pct_change'] == 0.0])/len(dataset))*100,2)
first_diff_zero = round((len(dataset[dataset['first_diff'] == 0.0])/len(dataset))*100,2)

# Threshold is 75%
if first_diff_zero >= threshold_val:
    print('No Model Possible')
else:
    print('Model Possible')

return pct_change_zero,first_diff_zero,dataset
```

> **This simple approach helps in identifying such target features, which are operating at a fixed value (`maybe sleeping/stable for the whole period`), and also helps in capturing the extent of oscillation
> occurred.**